Get object properties without including defaults
This is almost what I want:
MyList = list(vars(MyObject).keys())

But it gives me
['__module__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
I want a list without those default properties.What's currently the best way of doing that?

Use a List comprehension, not and startswith() to produce a new List excluding the elements you don't want.
